RN expo victory-native: TypeError: Cannot read property 'material' of undefined (a VictoryTheme)
Environment MacOS and Dependencies:
    “expo”: “51.0.12”
    “react”: “18.2.0”
    “react-native-reanimated”: “~3.10.1”
    “react-native-svg”: “^15.3.0”
    “victory-native”: “^41.0.0”

After updating my environment, my charts suddenly stopped working. The error is:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'material' of undefined

In fact, I found that none of the victory-native components are loading anymore. I tried logging VictoryTheme, but it also seems to be undefined.
Here are the import statements and the relevant code:
import { VictoryTheme } from 'victory-native';
import { 
    VictoryChart, 
    VictoryLine, 
    VictoryZoomContainer, 
    VictoryLabel, 
    VictoryAxis, 
    VictoryArea 
} from 'victory-native';

<VictoryChart 
    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
    width={screenWidth}
    height={220}
    scale={{ x: "time" }}
    padding={{ left: 20, top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 40 }} 
    containerComponent={<VictoryZoomContainer responsive={false} />}

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
